# How to produce a log-log rank/frequency plot?

Tags: r, graph, logging

I have a frequency and rank of words from a Wikipedia corpus that was processed. Just a row of x (word ranks) and y (frequencies) numbers and want a log-log plot in R that looks like this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wikipedia-n-zipf.png

How can I do that? I keep getting reversed or incorrect version. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just the base functions:

```
plot(x, y, log="xy")
```

This will plot your points on the log scale.

Answer (score 1):

With `lattice` and `latticeExtra`:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
xyplot((1:200)/20 ~ (1:200)/20, type = c('p', 'g'),
       scales = list(x = list(log = 10), y = list(log = 10)),
       xscale.components=xscale.components.log10ticks,
       yscale.components=yscale.components.log10ticks)
```

More examples [here](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#scale.components&theme=default).

Answer (score 1):

You have already down the hard work by getting the frequency and rank of words. You just need to plot them on a log scale.

```
##Word frequencies in Moby dick
dd = read.csv("http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/powerlaws/data/words.txt")

##Rename the columns and add in the rank
colnames(dd) = "freq"
dd$rank = 1:nrow(dd)

##Plot using base graphics
plot(dd$rank, dd$freq, log="xy")
```

Or you can use `ggplot2`

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dd, aes(x=rank, y=Freq)) +
  geom_point() + scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10()
```